# Does multiplying a matrix A by an elementary matrix E not change the solution space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $A$ be some matrix

$x$ complies with $Ax = 0$

How to show that for any elementary matrix $E$, $AEx = 0$ and vice versa?

---

I actually need to show that $Ax = 0 \iff ABx = 0$ for an invertible matrix $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove this, because it's false! For example, consider the case when
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}, E = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \vec x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then $A\vec x = \vec 0$ but $AE\vec x \ne \vec 0$.

However, you can show that if $E$ is an elementary matrix then $(EA)\vec x = \vec 0$ if and only if $A \vec x = \vec 0$ just by multiplying on the left by $E^{-1}$ (or by $E$ in the converse direction). But this doesn't require $E$ to be elementary; it just requires $E$ to be invertible.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, your `however` is what I wanted to show, but I need to show `Ax=0` iff `ABX=0` for any invertible B. I thought this would solve it... Can this case be solved?

Comment: @Gulzar: You mean $BA$, not $AB$ right? Otherwise we have the same issues as in my post. And I said how to prove it—take the equation $BA\vec x = \vec 0$ and multiply both sides on the left by $B^{-1}$. To go the other way around, take the equation $A \vec x = \vec 0$ and multiply on the left by $B$.